# Cannot get Laravel Welcome Page to appear on fresh install of Laravel

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have a fresh installation of Laravel using Homestead VM but cannot get the  `index.php` view for the project I created to display when I navigate to my mapped URL, I just get a Google `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Here is my `Homestead.yaml` file...

```
folders:
    - map: E:\LaravelProjects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: quickstart.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/quickstart/public
```

...and here is my mapping in hosts file

```
192.168.10.10 quickstart.local
```

I run `vagrant up` from the my local Homestead local repo copy, ssh in vagrant box, then created a new laravel project called  `quickstart` in path `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel`.

Comment: Are the necessary folders writable by the webserver?

Comment: I'm not sure how would I go about checking that? Total PHP/Laravel noob here. I mean it's Homestead shouldn't stuff like that be taken care of out of the box?